# Rails Aws s3 paperclip Doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

On local machime everithing working perfect. But when i deploy on Heroku doesnt work.

[Heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taCtH.png)

attachment_controller.rb:

```
class AttachmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @task = @project.tasks.find(params[:task_id])
  @attachment = @task.attachments.build(attachment_params)

  if @attachment.save
    redirect_to project_task_url(@project, @task)
  else
    redirect_to [@project, @task]
  end
end

def destroy
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @task = @project.tasks.find(params[:task_id])
  @attachment = @task.attachments.find(params[:id])
  @attachment.destroy
  redirect_to project_task_url(@project, @task)
end

def download
  attachment = Attachment.find(params[:id])

  send_file attachment.document.path,
            :filename => attachment.document_file_name,
            :type => attachment.document_content_type,
            :disposition => 'attachment'
end

private

def attachment_params
  params.require(:attachment).permit(:description, :document)
end
end
```

Instead of redirect to 
/projects/1/tasks/3/

they redirect to 
/projects/1/tasks/3/attachments

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users
root                  'static_pages#home'
get 'about'       =>  'static_pages#about'
get 'contact'     =>  'static_pages#contact'

resources :projects do
  resources :tasks, except: :index do
    resources :attachments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
end


match 'download/:id' =>  'attachments#download', :as => :download, via: [:get, :post]
end
```

tasks/show.html.erb:

```
...
<!-- ATTACHMENTS -->

<h3>Attachments</h3>
  <% if !@attachments.empty? %>
    <% @attachments.each do |attachment| %>
      <%= attachment.description %> |
      <%= link_to 'Download', download_path([attachment.task.project.id, attachment.task.id, attachment.id]) %> |
      <%= link_to "Preview", attachment.document.url(:original, false) %><br>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <p>Add an attachment</p>
  <% end %>
<br>

<!-- FORM FOR ATTACHMENTS -->

<%= form_for([@project, @task, @attachment], multipart: true) do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :document %>
    <%= f.file_field :document, class: 'form-control'%>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit 'Upload', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

task_controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.find(params[:id])

    @attachment = @task.attachments.build

    @attachments = @task.attachments
  end
```

production.rb:

```
 config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  } 
}
```

and heroku variables are configured.
can somebody help me?

Comment: What version of aws gem you use? And what did you out on aws_region?

Comment: im am region us-west-2, and i try aws-sdk '<2', and try latest version, but no one work.

Comment: Look into my setup on github: 'mvncaragay' under 'hyrav2' i used the latest gem and i believe i use iam credentials

Comment: https://github.com/mrvncaragay

Comment: Again error, when i run bundle and i got this:
https://s31.postimg.org/3zlquh2kb/Screenshot_from_2016_07_18_13_06_00.png
and heroku logs: 
https://s32.postimg.org/714l6j0n9/Screenshot_from_2016_07_18_13_02_47.png

Comment: Is there something wrong? 
https://s32.postimg.org/kzff59otx/Screenshot_from_2016_07_18_13_57_55.png
https://s31.postimg.org/7lcg37faj/Screenshot_from_2016_07_18_13_57_25.png
https://s32.postimg.org/wkeh4z0j9/Screenshot_from_2016_07_18_13_59_43.png
https://s32.postimg.org/t0eaqdx91/Screenshot_from_2016_07_18_14_00_40.png

Comment: can you upload your project on github and link me to it. Ill test it later on my machine.

Comment: https://github.com/kolekjr/todo_app

Comment: how do you add attachments me? i created a superadmin and project but i cant find the form to upload image to attachment.

Comment: Form is on tasks/show.html.erb, i upload files like txt, pdf.

Comment: i tried running it to heroku but getting a lots of error. sorry cant be more be helpful.